# Delphi XE2 Firemonkey sample app won't work on the MAC, dock icon bounces but nothing shows

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I saw the other thread that relates to this but I have a different problem. I've got everything set up according to the manual and suggestions from the other thread and I don't get any errors. The app actually shows up in the dock but that's where things come to a grinding halt. First it bounces for a long long time (minutes) and after it finally stops bouncing no window will show. I have no errors anywhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you debug this, or does this also happen when you try to run the app under the debugger?

Comment: Do you get any more output if you run it from terminal? If so, post the error message.

Comment: Did you actually start the PAServer on the Mac (if possible, through PAServer.command)? If not, that may be the reason your app doesn't start.

Comment: @Rudy :)  if it is a Mac VM, then you have a big chance that FireMonkey doesn't work. FireMonkey needs native GPU support on the Mac, and I don't think VMs provide that (yet?).

Comment: A Mac VM on a Windows machine is, well, not really according to Apple's license anyway. I have no idea if that is a problem. But the combination of FireMonkey on Windows in a VM (Parallels or VMWare Fusion) and the Mac OS X is without any problems. It does not have native GPU support there either, AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with a missing file in the XE2 installation

```
C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\binosx32\libcgunwind.1.0.dylib
```

The deployment process gives an error message about this missing file during the process of sending the app to the Mac, yet still says "success" in the end. Trying to run the app then gives a general error message on the Mac, but after copying this file from the PAServer folder on the Mac over to Windows and deploying again, everything works.